# How to call a variable that has not been created yet, but it will be, after running the code

Tags: python, dataframe, variables, global-variables, global

I have just created a code where I can get monthly DataFrames for many years just by inserting an input value and it works, but I would like to know how can I call those created variables of DataFrame to make others calculations.
Or maybe if there is another way to do that, I would apreciate you could tell me that. Thanks in advance.

My data was stored in a DataFrame named `data` and there is a column named `month`

```
   calculus = int(input("Which data do you want?: \n(1) month\n(2) anual\n"))

   # monthly data
   if calculus == 1:
       month = int(input(" Which month do you want? (1-12): "))
       globals()["month_" + str(month)] = data.loc[data['month'] == month]
```

Comment: Was there a error?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of these constructed variables.

Comment: There was not any error, that's all ok, I just want to know what to do after that @TheMaster

Comment: @KlausD. How could I do that? please help me

Comment: Using a dictionary is a very basic technique in Python. You might want to repeat that part from your Python course, book or tutorial.